# Loop though pandas DataFrame columns, sort, and return the top N results

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I am looking for help to optimize a function.

Data example (user_id is the DataFrame index):

```
df = 

user_id    670334    670336    670337    670338  670339  
670334  1.000000  0.995996  0.975368  0.995816     NaN   
670336  0.995996  1.000000  0.990686  0.999739     NaN   
670337  0.975368  0.990686  1.000000  0.990595     NaN   
670338  0.995816  0.999739  0.990595  1.000000     NaN
```

I am looking to take each column independently, sort it descending, then return a list of the top 200 user_ids. Below is what I have thus far but my matrix is over 8K x 8K data points.

```
#example function
def temp(df, N, column_head):

    #Saves only the info about the user
    xx = df[column_head]

    #Sorts descending removing NaN's
    data = xx.dropna().sort_values(ascending=False)

    #Returns user at hand and list of top 200 ids
    return column_head, list(data.index[1:N+1])
```

Then I use list comprehension

```
[temp(df, 200, x) for x in list(df.columns)]
```

Is there a better way to do this?? It does the job, but I feel like there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the data you've provided, here's a way to get the top `n`

```
i = df.index.values
v = df.values
n = 3
pd.DataFrame(i[v.argsort(0)[::-1]][:n], columns=df.columns)

   670334  670336  670337  670338  670339
0  670334  670336  670337  670338  670338
1  670336  670338  670336  670336  670337
2  670338  670334  670338  670334  670336
```

Comment: Beatuiful..! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use nlargest as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nlargest.html). For instance, you can edit your code as follows:

```
results = [list(df[x].nlargest(200).index) for x in list(df.columns)]
```

Comment: This method also does work, thank you! I needed just the user_id returned not the value also. Which the below accomplishes

[list(df[x].nlargest(200).index) for x in list(df.columns)]

Comment: @user2938093 you are right, I missed in the index part.